# What is the correct format of this?? I have a syntax error

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

```
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OlDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM[Sheet1$] Where Dormitory"+comboBox2.SelectedItem+" Where City"+comboBox1.SelectedItem+"",baglan);
```

I have an syntax error.
What is the correct format of this??

Comment: You need single space after `Dormitory` and `City`

Comment: And an equal sign after `Dormitory` and `City` as noted in the answer

Comment: The solution here is to stop building SQL like that in the first place. Use parameterized SQL, which will be a) clearer; b) safe from SQL injection attacks; c) more conversion-safe (particularly around dates).

Comment: @JonSkeet In addition to that, the solution is of course to use correct SQL syntax in the first place :-)

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: Yup - but that would become significantly easier to see (I suspect the OP would already have spotted it) if it weren't for the string concatenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put `WHERE` twice instead put `AND` at the second place & forgot to put `=`

```
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OlDbDataAdapter(@"SELECT * FROM[Sheet1$] 
   Where Dormitory='"+comboBox2.SelectedItem+"' AND City='"+comboBox1.SelectedItem+"'",baglan);
```

Note : It is vulnerable to SQLI. Better to use Prepared statements.

EDIT : As @Thorsten Dittmar said, if using string with spaces, then you should use single quotes

Comment: Please *don't* recommend solutions that continue with SQL Injection Attack vulnerabilities.

Comment: Please note that single quotes may be needed for string parameters. Also, please use parameterized queries to avoid SQL injections. If you use parameterized queries you can omit the single quotes.